# Photoshop: how to change text colour

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, text

I'm designing a poster where the background is black and white and I'm trying to change the colour of the font in the text box, but it stays black and white no matter what i do. Please help.

[image]

Comment: Did you check the document color mode? Sounds like it might be set to `Grayscale`. This menu can be found under `Image > Mode > ...`

Comment: no i purposely made the photo black and white because part of the photo was selected to be in color so the rest would be black and white however anything i put in the gray space now is now also black and white.... short on time so i may just redo the selection and go through hell selecting each letter...

Comment: Can you add an image to your post? Might help to clear up what exactly  you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: done... no matter what i do to the text it never changes color unless i edit the main selection i used in the first place to make the photo black and white

Comment: You might need to bring the black and white photo in as a separate asset. Try setting up a new doc with the color mode set to CMYK (if you're planning on printing) and place the photo in it. Then just recreate the text on a new layer.

Comment: Also, use the Character  palette (`Window > Character`) to edit the text color.

Answer (score 0):

If you're editing the text/selection on the same layer, it seems like even if you select out the text areas, whatever you did to make the photo gray is also already applied to that text area. Try jumping the selected text to a new layer using Layer via Copy/Cut, then recolor it? In the top menu try Layer -> New -> one of the above options

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help, I solved this by creating by desired test on an entirely different document and then making a selection of the letters (ctrl-click on T) and then pasting into the original document. The colours, font, font size, font style, and leading all stayed the same through the copy/paste process.

Comment: Maybe you had the problem because you had a "Black and White" adjustment layer with a mask. Then you had the text beneath the B&W layer. Couldn't you just have moved the text layer above the B&W layer?
And another thing. When you are making something for print you should always work with vector text. Pixel based text doesn't look crisp and can't be used for small text. No matter how high res it is. 
I recommend separating the components of a project: Text is written in a text editor, images are manipulated in Photoshop and everything is put together in either InDesign or Illustrator.